# How to remove unanalytics.com adware from chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Since the last couple of days I receive the following message on all of my pc's in chrome browser from time to time:

[image: chrome warning message]

How can I remove it? All guides on internet give instructions for the Windows platform, not ubuntu. I've checked already in my extensions but I've seen nothing suspicious.

Strangely enough, it's on all of my pc's even one on which is not syncronised through my google-account.

Edit: a list of all my installed extensions:

```
CookiesOK : version 5_2
Web Store : version 0_2
Documenten : version 0_10
Google Drive : version 14_1
YouTube : version 4_2_8
Google Search : version 0_0_0_60
I don't care about cookies : version 2_8_3
Feedback : version 1_0
Offline Documenten : version 1_4
Google Play Music : version 5_5
Screensharing for Nextcloud Video calls app : version 1_0_0
CryptoTokenExtension : version 0_9_73
Cloud Print : version 0_1
Chrome PDF Viewer : version 1
Pocket : version 0_810
Google Network Speech : version 1_0
Save to Pocket : version 3_0_4_0
Google Hangouts : version 1_3_7
Betalingen via Chrome Web Store : version 1_0_0_4
Better History : version 3_9_20
Gmail : version 8_1
Chrome Media Router : version 6618_312_0_2
```

Comment: Can you list all of the extensions you have installed on Google Chrome?

Comment: I've added a list of all my extensions in my original post.

Comment: Does it happen with Firefox as well? Are you using a proxy? Try switching your DNS to Clouldflare's `1.1.1.1` or Google's `8.8.8.8`.

Comment: For all you non-dutch readers "misleading site detected" is the title of the image.And I can confirm ASB's findings: It is this one "Better History : version 3_9_20"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an article which mentioned Better History was the cause,  i removed that and not had this issues since.  Give that a try.

Comment: Detailed info can be found here https://www.reddit.com/r/Malware/comments/4cw9fz/lnkrus_redirect_malware_report/

Comment: Thanks, I've removed it on one pc. I'll wait a bit and see if it returns or not and keep you informed.

Comment: Haven't encountered any red screens on the pc where I disabled Better History but also on my other pc's. So maybe this was temporarily? Anyway, problem solved. Thanks.